# segmentaion fault in deletion of node in B-tree

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Segmentation fault in btree implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471765/segmentation-fault-in-btree-implementation)

I had already posted this question earlier asking for a help and i got some suggestion of how to debug, but still i am stuck in the same segmentation fault problem and not able to remove it please help me out, i have started c coding and i tried my best to debug it before posting it here again

Here M  is the order of the tree, M = 5 means it can have 5 children and 4 keys,
1> press 1 it will insert keys automatically,( here i have input 20 numbers using a loop) so just press 1 data will be entered.

2 > Press 4 it will display.

3> Then go for delete option, if i try deleting either 71/84 it give an segmentation fault or throws memory map.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    #define M 5 

    struct node{
        int n; /* n < M No. of keys in node will always less than order of B
              tree */
        int keys[M-1]; /*array of keys*/
        struct node *p[M]; /* (n+1 pointers will be in use) */
    }*root=NULL;

    enum KeyStatus { Duplicate,SearchFailure,Success,InsertIt,LessKeys };

    void insert(int key);
    void display(struct node *root,int);
    void DelNode(int x);
    void search(int x);
    enum KeyStatus ins(struct node *r, int x, int* y, struct node** u);
    int searchPos(int x,int *key_arr, int n);
    enum KeyStatus del(struct node *r, int x);
    int input_array[20]= {65,67,71,78,72,69,75,81,77,70,87,76,84,90,68,80,82,88,89,83};
    int main()
    {

        int choice, i,key;
        printf("Creation of B tree for node %d\n",M);
        while(1)
        {
            printf("1.Insert\n");
            printf("2.Delete\n");
            printf("3.Search\n");
            printf("4.Display\n");
            printf("5.Quit\n");
            printf("Enter your choice : ");
            scanf("%d",&choice);

            switch(choice)
            {
                case 1:
                    //printf("Enter the key : ");
                    //scanf("%d",&key);
                    for(i=0;i<20;i++)
                     {
                        key = input_array[i];
                        insert(key);
                     } 
                    //insert(key++);
                    //insert(key);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    printf("Enter the key : ");
                    scanf("%d",&key);
                    DelNode(key);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    printf("Enter the key : ");
                    scanf("%d",&key);
                    search(key);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    printf("Btree is :\n");
                    display(root,0);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    exit(1);
                default:
                    printf("Wrong choice\n");
                    break;
            }/*End of switch*/
        }/*End of while*/
        return 0;
    }/*End of main()*/

    void insert(int key)
    {
        struct node *newnode;
        int upKey;
        enum KeyStatus value;
        value = ins(root, key, &upKey, &newnode);
        if (value == Duplicate)
            printf("Key already available\n");
        if (value == InsertIt)
        {
            struct node *uproot = root;
            root=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
            root->n = 1;
            root->keys[0] = upKey;
            root->p[0] = uproot;
            root->p[1] = newnode;
        }/*End of if */
    }/*End of insert()*/

    enum KeyStatus ins(struct node *ptr, int key, int *upKey,struct node **newnode)
    {
        struct node *newPtr, *lastPtr;
        int pos, i, n,splitPos;
        int newKey, lastKey;
        enum KeyStatus value;
        if (ptr == NULL)
        {
            *newnode = NULL;
            *upKey = key;
            return InsertIt;
        }
        n = ptr->n;
        pos = searchPos(key, ptr->keys, n);

        if (pos < n && key == ptr->keys[pos])
            return Duplicate;
        value = ins(ptr->p[pos], key, &newKey, &newPtr);
        if (value != InsertIt)
            return value;
        /*If keys in node is less than M-1 where M is order of B tree*/
        if (n < M - 1)
        {
            pos = searchPos(newKey, ptr->keys, n);
            /*Shifting the key and pointer right for inserting the new key*/
            for (i=n; i>pos; i--)
            {
                ptr->keys[i] = ptr->keys[i-1];
                ptr->p[i+1] = ptr->p[i];
            }
            /*Key is inserted at exact location*/
            ptr->keys[pos] = newKey;
            ptr->p[pos+1] = newPtr;
            ++ptr->n; /*incrementing the number of keys in node*/
            return Success;
        }/*End of if */
        /*If keys in nodes are maximum and position of node to be inserted is
          last*/
        if (pos == M - 1)
        {
            lastKey = newKey;
            lastPtr = newPtr;
        }
        else /*If keys in node are maximum and position of node to be inserted
               is not last*/
        {
            lastKey = ptr->keys[M-2];
            lastPtr = ptr->p[M-1];
            for (i=M-2; i>pos; i--)
            {
                ptr->keys[i] = ptr->keys[i-1];
                ptr->p[i+1] = ptr->p[i];
            }
            ptr->keys[pos] = newKey;
            ptr->p[pos+1] = newPtr;
        }
        splitPos = (M - 1)/2;
        (*upKey) = ptr->keys[splitPos];

        (*newnode)=malloc(sizeof(struct node));/*Right node after split*/
        ptr->n = splitPos; /*No. of keys for left splitted node*/
        (*newnode)->n = M-1-splitPos;/*No. of keys for right splitted node*/
        for (i=0; i < (*newnode)->n; i++)
        {
            (*newnode)->p[i] = ptr->p[i + splitPos + 1];
            if(i < (*newnode)->n - 1)
                (*newnode)->keys[i] = ptr->keys[i + splitPos + 1];
            else
                (*newnode)->keys[i] = lastKey;
        }
        (*newnode)->p[(*newnode)->n] = lastPtr;
        return InsertIt;
    }/*End of ins()*/

    void display(struct node *ptr, int blanks)
    {
        if (ptr)
        {
            int i;
            for(i=1;i<=blanks;i++)
                printf(" ");
            for (i=0; i < ptr->n; i++)
                printf("%d ",ptr->keys[i]);
            printf("\n");
            for (i=0; i <= ptr->n; i++)
                display(ptr->p[i], blanks+10);
        }/*End of if*/
    }/*End of display()*/

    void search(int key)
    {
        int pos, i, n;
        struct node *ptr = root;
        printf("Search path:\n");
        while (ptr)
        {
            n = ptr->n;
            for (i=0; i < ptr->n; i++)
                printf(" %d",ptr->keys[i]);
            printf("\n");
            pos = searchPos(key, ptr->keys, n);
            if (pos < n && key == ptr->keys[pos])
            {
                printf("Key %d found in position %d of last dispalyednode\n",key,i);
                return;
            }
            ptr = ptr->p[pos];
        }
        printf("Key %d is not available\n",key);
    }/*End of search()*/

    int searchPos(int key, int *key_arr, int n)
    {
        int pos=0;
        while (pos < n && key > key_arr[pos])
            pos++;
        return pos;
    }/*End of searchPos()*/

    void DelNode(int key)
    {
        struct node *uproot;
        enum KeyStatus value;
        value = del(root,key);
        switch (value)
        {
            case SearchFailure:
                printf("Key %d is not available\n",key);
                break;
            case LessKeys:
                uproot = root;
                root = root->p[0];
                free(uproot);
                break;
        }/*End of switch*/
    }/*End of delnode()*/

    enum KeyStatus del(struct node *ptr, int key)
    {
        int pos, i, pivot, n ,min;
        int *key_arr;
        enum KeyStatus value;
        struct node **p,*lptr,*rptr;

        if (ptr == NULL)
            return SearchFailure;
        /*Assigns values of node*/
        n=ptr->n;
        key_arr = ptr->keys;
        p = ptr->p;
        min = (M - 1)/2;/*Minimum number of keys*/

        pos = searchPos(key, key_arr, n);
        if (p[0] == NULL)
        {
            if (pos == n || key < key_arr[pos])
                return SearchFailure;
            /*Shift keys and pointers left*/
            for (i=pos+1; i < n; i++)
            {
                key_arr[i-1] = key_arr[i];
                p[i] = p[i+1];
            }
            return --ptr->n >= (ptr==root ? 1 : min) ? Success : LessKeys;
        }/*End of if */

        if (pos < n && key == key_arr[pos])
        {
            struct node *qp = p[pos], *qp1;
            int nkey;
            while(1)
            {
                nkey = qp->n;
                qp1 = qp->p[nkey];
                if (qp1 == NULL)
                    break;
                qp = qp1;
            }/*End of while*/
            key_arr[pos] = qp->keys[nkey-1];
            qp->keys[nkey - 1] = key;
        }/*End of if */
        value = del(p[pos], key);
        if (value != LessKeys)
            return value;

        if (pos > 0 && p[pos-1]->n > min)
        {
            pivot = pos - 1; /*pivot for left and right node*/
            lptr = p[pivot];
            rptr = p[pos];
            /*Assigns values for right node*/
            rptr->p[rptr->n + 1] = rptr->p[rptr->n];
            for (i=rptr->n; i>0; i--)
            {
                rptr->keys[i] = rptr->keys[i-1];
                rptr->p[i] = rptr->p[i-1];
            }
            rptr->n++;
            rptr->keys[0] = key_arr[pivot];
            rptr->p[0] = lptr->p[lptr->n];
            key_arr[pivot] = lptr->keys[--lptr->n];
            return Success;
        }/*End of if */
        if (pos > min)
        {
            pivot = pos; /*pivot for left and right node*/
            lptr = p[pivot];
            rptr = p[pivot+1];
            /*Assigns values for left node*/
            lptr->keys[lptr->n] = key_arr[pivot];
            lptr->p[lptr->n + 1] = rptr->p[0];
            key_arr[pivot] = rptr->keys[0];
            lptr->n++;
            rptr->n--;
            for (i=0; i < rptr->n; i++)
            {
                rptr->keys[i] = rptr->keys[i+1];
                rptr->p[i] = rptr->p[i+1];
            }/*End of for*/
            rptr->p[rptr->n] = rptr->p[rptr->n + 1];
            return Success;
        }/*End of if */

        if(pos == n)
            pivot = pos-1;
        else
            pivot = pos;

        lptr = p[pivot];
        rptr = p[pivot+1];
        /*merge right node with left node*/
        lptr->keys[lptr->n] = key_arr[pivot];
        lptr->p[lptr->n + 1] = rptr->p[0];
        for (i=0; i < rptr->n; i++)
        {
            lptr->keys[lptr->n + 1 + i] = rptr->keys[i];
            lptr->p[lptr->n + 2 + i] = rptr->p[i+1];
        }
        lptr->n = lptr->n + rptr->n +1;
        free(rptr); /*Remove right node*/
        for (i=pos+1; i < n; i++)
        {
            key_arr[i-1] = key_arr[i];
            p[i] = p[i+1];
        }
        return --ptr->n >= (ptr == root ? 1 : min) ? Success : LessKeys;
    }/*End of del()*/
```

Comment: You can't possibly expect us to visually debug that much code. As suggested in your previous question, compile with the debug `-g` flag with gcc, and then run gdb on your program. When the segfault happens, gdb should intercept it. Type `bt` for a backtrace, and it will tell you exactly what line and what function caused the segfault as well as reveal the call stack. This should be enough information to find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot to sift through, and this kind of stuff isn't easy (on purpose!)

Something that jumps out at me is this

```
if (p[0] == NULL)
    {
        if (pos == n || key < key_arr[pos])
            return SearchFailure;
        /*Shift keys and pointers left*/
        for (i=pos+1; i < n; i++)
        {
            key_arr[i-1] = key_arr[i];
            p[i] = p[i+1];
        }
        return --ptr->n >= (ptr==root ? 1 : min) ? Success : LessKeys;
    }/*End of if */
```

What if p[1] is also null? All that will do is move p[1] into p[0]. Perhaps you need a function called "node reduce" or something that "moves the nodes to the front of the node?"

Answer (score 0):

I found the error causing segmentation fault in this case by valgrind, and answered it in your other post. Please have a look at [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5471765/segmentation-fault-in-btree-implementation/5635065#5635065).